# How to make Javascript function changeImage() remove item

Tags: javascript, image, function, button, simplecart

When button is pressed two functions occur. the first function is "item1" is added to cart and the second function is the button image is changed from "add.png" to "minus.png". After having the button switch to "minus.png" the desired outcome is to have the item removed from the cart and the image transition to its original "add.png" if the button is pressed again.
http://simplecartjs.org/documentation/simplecart-item-remove

Sample of button in action: http://jsfiddle.net/9kmun19z/

```html
<img id="button" onclick="addbeat(event);changeImage()" name="item1" src="add.png"/>

<script>
function addbeat(event) {
simpleCart.add({
     name: event.target.name,
     price: .99
 });
}
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('button');
    if (image.src.match("minus")) {
        image.src = "add.png";
    } else {
        image.src = "minus.png";
simpleCart.item.remove();({
     name: event.target.name,
     price: .99
 });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? The code isnt working here on stack.

Comment: here is a sample of the button semi working http://jeffdbeats.com/simplecart/

Comment: There's an error in this line :

SimpleCart.item.remove();({
     name: event.target.name,
     price: .99
 });

Comment: And accessing your code is difficult for me. Can you make a fiddle, here .. http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9kmun19z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery, it will help you alot.

see this example:

```
<img id="button" data-product-id="XYZ" name="items" src="add.png"/>


<script>
$("#button").toggle(function(){
    //first functon here
    simpleCart.add({
     name: $(this).attr("data-product-id"),
     price: .99
    });
    //we set src of image with jquery
    $(this).attr("src", "image/path/to_1.png");
},function(){
    //second function here
    //simplecart remove function here, this isjust example, adjust with your code
    simpleCart.remove({
     name: $(this).attr("data-product-id")
    });
    $(this).attr("src", "image/path/to_2.png");
});
</script>
```

Comment: should I put onclick somewhere?

Comment: not need anymore, look into toggle(), event's click already handled by toggle's function. as I said jquery make us work fast.
may you want check full-docs here http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: Thanks Kadugeboy, I got the Jquery to work, I just needed to link to Jquery 1.7 and change the remove function around a little.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use two buttons to meet your needs.

bind different functions to the two buttons;

using css display:none/block to controll which button will show.

then everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you put the simple cart remove in the wrong branch - you want to remove the item when the minus button is showing

```
function changeImage() {
 var image = document.getElementById('button');
 if (image.src.match("minus")) {
   simpleCart.item.remove();({
     name: event.target.name,
     price: .99
     });
   image.src = "add.png";
   } else {
   image.src = "minus.png";
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It took a little messing around but I was able to get the desired effect using the Jquery recommended by Kadugedboy along with quantity=1 and quantity=-1 in the functions, One thing you will have to do is make sure Jquery 1.7 or lower is installed because they removed the toggle() feature in the newer versions.

```html
<img class="button" data-product-id="XYZ" src="add.png"/>


<script>
$(".button").toggle(function(){
    //first functon here
    simpleCart.add({
     name: $(this).attr("data-product-id"),
     price: .99,
  quantity: 1
    });
    //we set src of image with jquery
    $(this).attr("src", "minus.png");
},function(){
    //second function here
    //simplecart remove function here, this isjust example, adjust with your code
 simpleCart.add({
     name: $(this).attr("data-product-id"),
     price: .99,
  quantity: -1
    });
    $(this).attr("src", "add.png");
});
</script>
```